# Control direction of lines around earth

Tags: qgis, antimeridian

in QGIS 3.4.14, I am trying to draw a line from Los Angeles to Tokyo. With an XYZ Tile base map turned on, the line goes east from Los Angeles (over Africa) to Tokyo. I would like the line to appear going west from Los Angeles (similar to the direction a plane would fly).

Is there a way to redefine the center of my base map and force the line to go the opposite direction?

Comment: You must be using a coordinate reference system that is split in the middle of the Pacific Ocean. Look for a CRS that has its split somewhere else.